# Open Set Clarification: Sequence Definition

Tags: general-topology

Given a point, $x$, in a metric space $(X, d)$. I am trying to show the two bullets below are tied together by an iff.

- $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N}: (n\in \mathbb{N} \text { and } 
   n\geq N\rightarrow d(x_n,x)<\epsilon$)
- $\forall$ open set $U$ containing $x$, $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}: [(n\in \mathbb{N} \text { and } n\geq N) \rightarrow x_n\in U$]

I worked out the problem this far, but I am confused as far by the terminology $\forall$ open set $U$ containing $x$, as I think it would refer to $\forall U\ni x$, which does not make much sense to me.

> $\textbf{Question:}$ How do get $\bigcup_
> {x\in B\subseteq U} B$ to just be $U$ with these quantifiers? I feel like I am misinterpreting something with my notation here and making this problem more difficult than it needs to be.

\begin{align*} 
\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N}: (n\in \mathbb{N} \text { and } 
 n\geq N\rightarrow d(x_n,x)<\epsilon)&\leftrightarrow  \exists N\in \mathbb{N}: (n\in \mathbb{N} \text { and } 
 n\geq N\rightarrow d(x_n,x)<\delta )\\
&\leftrightarrow  \exists N\in \mathbb{N}: (n\in \mathbb{N} \text { and } 
 n\geq N\rightarrow x_n\in B(x; \delta) )\\
&\leftrightarrow  \exists N\in \mathbb{N}: (n\in \mathbb{N} \text { and } 
 n\geq N\rightarrow x_n\in \bigcup_{x\in B\subseteq U} B ).
\end{align*}

Comment: In you second bullet, where do you use $N$? Only $n$ appears. I assume that you wanted to say $n > N$.

Comment: I'll edit that, that's my fault

Comment: I fixed it now. Sorry about that

Comment: The second bullet says that if $U$ is open and if $x\in U$ then $\exists N\in \Bbb N\;(\forall n\geq N\;(x_n\in U)\;).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the union you wrote, $\bigcup_
{x_n\in B\subseteq U} B$, *is* $U$, because in particular $U \subseteq U$ and it contains some $x_n$ of your sequence. No "bigger" set can be in this union since this would imply that it is not contained in $U$. I believe this answers your question alone, though does not show the iff between the two bullets.

Comment: I edited the answer a little bit. But how does $\bigcup_{x\in B\subseteq U}B=U$? Assume $j\in U$. Then, how does $j\in \bigcup_{x\in B\subseteq U}B$?

Comment: The thing is that $x$ is a given variable. So, $\exists B: j\in B\subseteq U$, but that doesn't mean it is in that set correct?

Comment: If by $\bigcup_{x\in B\subseteq U}B=U$ you mean "each $B$ is a set contained in $U$ and has $x$ as an element", well, then $U$ is contained in $U$ and $x\in U$ by hypothesis. Am I interpreting these sets B wrong? And then, if you take a $j\in U$, by the preceding construction $j\in \bigcup_{x\in B\subseteq U}B=U$

Comment: The preceding construction part is what I am confused on, i.e. showing $j\in U \implies j\in \bigcup_{x\in B\subseteq U}B$. The thing that I am having a hard time with is that the variable $x$ it is an already determined point in $X$, so $x$ cannot be $j$ right away even though it looks like it.

Comment: Let's make an explicit construction. Take an open ball centered at $x$ of radius $\lvert x - j \rvert + \epsilon$, that is, an open ball just big enough to have $x$ and $j$ as elements, but small enough to be contained in the "big" set $U$. Such a set Is contained in $\bigcup_{x\in B\subseteq U}B$, because it fits the union restraints: it does have $x$ as an element, and it is contained in $U$. So $j$ is in the union. This construction is possible because $U$ itself is an open set, and $j$ an interior point. :)

Comment: Keeping $x$ fixed "where it is" since the start!

Comment: $x$ and $j$ are in $X$ though, so they don't have to be real numbers, so having a radius $|x-j|+\epsilon$ is confusing to me.

Comment: Yup, $x$ and $j$ do not need to be "numbers", they are elements of your topological space in question. This radius condition is to guarantee that $j$ is inside the ball constructed.

Answer (score 0):

The first to the second follows from the fact that in a metric space by definition we have: $x \in U$ and $U$ open implies that there is some $\varepsilon >0$ with $B(x,\varepsilon) \subseteq U$. Then we apply the first bullet to this $\varepsilon$ and we're done, as $d(x_n,x) < \varepsilon$ iff $x_n \in B(x,\varepsilon)$ etc.

For the second to the first we only need to know that for every $\varepsilon>0$, the set $B(x,\varepsilon)$ is an open set containing $x$, so we can apply the second bullet to this set as our $U$.